# How to check if the .sig file is correct?

Tags: tls, openssl

I issued the following commands to create a signature for a file (Linux kernel) :

```
openssl req -newkey rsa -keyout codesign.key -out codesign.req
openssl ca -config ca.cnf -extensions codesigning -in codesign.req -out codesign.crt

openssl cms -sign -binary -noattr -in vmlinuz -signer codesign.crt -inkey codesign.key -certfile ca.crt -outform DER -out vmlinuz.sig
```

The `ca.cnf` file is for my own private CA infrastructure and it has digitalSignature key usage extension and the codeSigning extended key usage extension enabled.

Ca.cnf format:

[ ca ]

default_ca             = ca_default

[ ca_default ]

certificate            = ca.crt

private_key            = ca.key

serial                 = ca.srl

database               = ca.idx

new_certs_dir          = /home/apoorv/projects/signed

default_md             = default

policy                 = policy_anything

preserve               = yes

default_days           = 90

unique_subject         = no

[ policy_anything ]

countryName            = optional

stateOrProvinceName    = optional

localityName           = optional

organizationName       = optional

organizationalUnitName = optional

commonName             = optional

emailAddress           = optional

[ cross ]

basicConstraints       = critical,CA:true

keyUsage               = critical,cRLSign,keyCertSign

[ codesigning ]

keyUsage                = digitalSignature

extendedKeyUsage        = codeSigning

Command : openssl cms -verify -binary -content vmlinuz -inform DER -in vmlinuz.sig -CAfile ca.crt

Output:

Verification failure 140187569694352:error:2E099064:CMS routines:CMS_SIGNERINFO_VERIFY_CERT:certificate verify error:cms_smime.c:287:Verify error:unsupported certificate purpose

Could you please provide any input ?? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As should be clear from the manpage on your system [or online](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/cms.html) assuming the CA cert specified in your ca.cnf is ca.crt and is the root cert, the basic function you want is

```
openssl cms -verify -binary -content vmlinuz -inform der -in vmlinuz.sig -CAfile ca.crt
```

except by default it requires ExtendedKeyUsage if present includes "emailProtection" id-pkix 3 4 not (solely) codeSigning; to override that add `-purpose any`.

If the cert hierarchy is more complicated -- i.e. if it uses a chain -- then there are a variety of cases depending on what cert(s) you included in the signature file with `-certfile`, what cert(s) are in your default or specified trustore file and/or directory and in `-certfile` if used and whether you specify `-partial_chain` in 1.0.2 up, and without a more specific question I don't have time to write that much.

Comment: I updated my question. Could you please have a look at it ? Thanks Dave :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @dave_thompson_085 for helping. Adding the purpose -any option solved our problem.

Comment: @apoorvmunshi you're welcome, but the StackExchange way is to mark accepted and/or vote [as discussed at this link](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) rather than 'thanks'.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 ...and maybe to upvote too. But if they also upvote...  you will remain tenacious without being an _unsung hero_  `:-)`